# URL Scheme iOS | Open Source Application Programmtically

Tags: ios, url-scheme

I have 2 `iOS` applications, using `URL Scheme` I am able to open app `B` through `A` like I have created `URL Scheme` in `B` and using `OpenURL` calling it from application `B`. Also, I am able to pass the data.

But what I am looking for, is there a way to move back to application `A` on some specific event.

In `B` I am getting all details about `A` in `sourceApplication` but how to move back?

Do we need to create `URL Scheme` for both of the apps for communicating with each other? or is there any way to invoke `sourceApplication` and move back?

**Issue 1**

in case of `Facebook SDK,` I create `URL Scheme` for my app because once authentication is done I want `Facebook SDK` to call my app that right but I didn't register my app `scheme` in `Facebook SDK` info.plist. how does it work?

**Issue 2**
I have tried on Simulator and device both. if I call `canOpenURL` it gives me an error

> -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "openb://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme openb"

But If I directly call `UIApplication.shared.open` it launches the application successfully.

Any leads here?

Comment: Use another URL scheme?

Comment: you mean in that case we have to register `URL Scheme` for both apps for communicating each other?

Comment: yes, one URL scheme for each app, so they can call each other.

Comment: You mean `URL Scheme` for both `A` and `B`. but when I am invoking `B` from `A` can we move back we have all details about `sourceApplication`? `Facebook iOS SDK` does the same then how they are achieving it? any idea?

Comment: I mean each one has its own URL scheme so you can call it. Haven’t used the Facebook SDK in a while, but last time I did it used that method, and you were required to add an URL scheme containing your app id to return to your app (in the case the Facebook SDK actually opened the Facebook app — IIRC it now uses an SFSafariViewController whenever it can).

Comment: Yes correct, we create `URL Scheme` while using `Facebook SDK` but we didn't register our app scheme within Facebook App. I mean if i create `URL Scheme` for `A` we have to register it with `B` as we don't do this in case of `Facebook`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to invoke `iOS` application from another `iOS` app `URL Scheme` is the way. A URL scheme lets you communicate with other apps through a protocol that you define. To communicate with an app that implements such a scheme, you must create an appropriately formatted URL and ask the system to open it. To implement support for a custom scheme, you must declare support for the scheme and handle incoming URLs that use the scheme.

> How to move back or open sourceApplication?

To achieve this you have to create `URL Scheme` for both of the application.

> Issue 1 and 2

Before iOS 8, everyone was using `canOpenURL` for checking whether this `URL` is exist for not and if yes `openURL` for invoking the application. But concern came when few developers/apps started using it to track the user iPhone (what all application is installed) for advertising purposes etc. That's why `Apple` came up with the solution called `URL Scheme Whitelist`.

So according to that, if you want to use `canOpenURL` you have to whitelist the `URL Scheme` otherwise it will through an error like `error: This app is not allowed to query for scheme` and if you want to open the application use `openURL` directly.

Yes it broke lots of SDKs login flow but it makes sense.

For more information, [canOpenURL(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622952-canopenurl)